# Send mail function in java doesnt send .zip as the attachment

Tags: java, email, zip

This send mail function is working for all types of files like .html,.txt as attachment. But when i try to send a .zip folder as attachment , it terminates.

```
public void sendmail(){
       System.out.println("started function");
        String from = "amritharajeevan.77@gmail.com";
            // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
            String to = "amritha2.rajeevan@aricent.com";

            final String username = "amritharajeevan.77";//change accordingly
            final String password = "vivekrajeevan";//change accordingly

            // Assuming you are sending email through gmail.com
            String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
               new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                  protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                     return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                  }
               });

            try {
               Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
               message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
               message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                  InternetAddress.parse(to));
               message.setSubject("Server Error");
               BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
               messageBodyPart.setText("Server"+" " +servererror+ " " +" is unreachable. Please check the logs.");
               Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
               multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
               messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
               String filename = "/Users/aricent/Desktop/amritha/seetest/May6.zip";
               DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
               messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
               messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
               multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
               message.setContent(multipart);
               System.out.println("sent start function");
               Transport.send(message);

               System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
         }
```

So i dont know what to do? please tell me what part of my code should i change. I tried for .txt and .html files. It works fine.

Comment: Any Exceptions? If so, please add stacktrace info.

Comment: I think you need to set the MIME type for the attachment. It needs to be appropriate for zip files. Cant remember the exact format, but it will bne on the web somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Apache Commons Email project, which will clean up a lot of this code and make attachments easy.

```
    // Create the attachment
    EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
    attachment.setPath(zipFile);
    attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
    attachment.setDescription("Zip File");
    attachment.setName("myfiles.zip");

    MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
    email.attach(attachment);
```